# Unable to upload image using Upload button using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

trying to upload a an image file using Java selenium

Hi all, I am trying to upload a an image file using Java selenium

below is the code:
first approach:

```
WebElement upload_file = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of upload button"));
upload_file .click();
// just passed a delay, it does not crate a problem I can remove it
java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000); 
//full file path present in my local machine
        uplaod_file.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Pictures\\Files\\image.jpg");
        System.out.println("File is Uploaded Successfully");
```

Issue observed :org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Second approach:

```
        By upload_file_button = By.xpath("xpath of upload button");
        explicit_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(upload_file_button));
        driver.findElement(upload_file_button).click();
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000);
        ((WebElement) upload_file_button).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Pictures\\Files\\image.jpg");
        System.out.println("File is Uploaded Successfully");
```

Issue observed : org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: xpath of upload button (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

need help for same, please do correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Uploading file by Selenium is normally done as following:
You can send the uploading file full path to the special element on the web page. This is not the "Upload" visible button but a special element with `input` tag name and `type` attribute with `file` value. As a user you can't see it on the page but can find it with use of dev tools. So, this element can be located by the following XPath: `//input[@type='file']`.
So, to upload your file try this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Pictures\\Files\\image.jpg");
```

Comment: Hey Prophet, you really are a prophet.

it worked out ... thanks

Comment: No, I'm not a real prophet. Also not a genius. Just somewhat experienced :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't click on the upload file prompt, you are just sending it the file's path. Later, click on the send / upload file button.

```
upload_file.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Pictures\\Files\\image.jpg");
upload_button = driver.findElement(By.Xpath, '//*[text()="upload"]');
upload_button.click();
```

Comment: Thanks @Tal Angel

, but facing issue

Below is my modified code:

WebElement browse = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__next\"]/div[2]/div/main/div/div[1]/div[1]/label"));

   browse.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Pictures\\Files\\nft.jpg"); 

browse.click();